# 301 redirect for www and non-www canonical problems

Tags: iis, redirect, canonical-name

i have a web site on a Microsoft IIS Web Server and my web site consists of simple static HTML pages.

I need to solve my canonical problems as the following are all valid for my page:

http://www.nurcanaral.com
http://nurcanaral.com

I want all of the above addresses to be redirected to www only. All the searches I've done give me .htaccess solutions for Apache servers. But this is not valid for my server.  I don't have much experience with server coding. Is there a way to achieve the above solution within the page code itself?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create two websites in IIS for each site. For example:

First Site:
Name: nurcanaral
Bindings: www.nurcanaral.com:80

Second Site:
Name: nurcanaral-www
Bindings: nurcanaral.com:80

For the second site, you will need to configure HTTP Redirect options as shown in image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfaSE.jpg